# Azure devops Deploy to Kubernetes task succeeds if kubernetes Job exitCode is nonzero

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When deploying the below [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) to Azure AKS the exitCode is nonzero but the deploy task succeeds. The question is

how to make [Deploy to Kubernetes task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/kubernetes/deploy?view=azure-devops) fail if exit code of Job or Pod is nonzero?

```
#kubectl get pod --selector=job-name=job-pod-failure-policy-example  -o jsonpath='{.items[-1:]..exitCode}' 
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job-pod-failure-policy-example
spec:
  completions: 12
  parallelism: 3
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: main
        image: docker.io/library/bash:5
        command: ["bash"]        # example command simulating a bug which triggers the FailJob action
        args:
        - -c
        - echo "Hello world!" && sleep 5 && exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

***I have created the pod and deployed into the cluster***

```
vi job-pod-failure-policy-example.yaml

kubectl apply -f filename.yaml

kubectl get pods    #to check the pods
```

[image]

***To check the logs use the below command***

```
kubectl describe pod pod_name
```

[image]

***When I check the the exit code using below command its 0 because of pod run successfully***

```
kubectl get pod --selector=job-name=job-pod-failure-policy-example  -o jsonpath='{.items[-1:]..exitCode}'
```

[image]

***Here I have created and deployed the file with exit code 1***

[image]

***When I check the logs below I got exit code 1 because the application failed***

[image]

***We can also have different types of jobs or pods with exit code is non zero***

***I have created the sample file and deployed***

```
#vi crashbackoop.yaml
#kubectl apply -f filename

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: privetae-image-testing
spec:
  containers:
    - name: private-image-test
      image: buildforjenkin.azurecr.io/nginx:latest
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      command: ['echo','success','sleep 1000000']
```

***When I check the logs I got the ErrImage error***

[image]

[image]

***The above error we will get if the image path is not correct or kubelet does not succeeded in authenticating with container registry***

***For more about exit code non zero please [refer this link](https://komodor.com/learn/exit-codes-in-containers-and-kubernetes-the-complete-guide/)***